# Login and register android application using SQLite database

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

Good day coders. I've created a login and register application. For this past week I've been through so many tutorials on youtube but nothing, trust me, nothing can help me. Stackoverflow is my last hope. I'm struggling to save the registration information to the SQlite database. I've checked the database and there is no values in it. My code is below

```
 public void insertRegister() {
        try {
            String Username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
            String Password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
            String Name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String ConfirmPassword = txtConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            String Email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
            Boolean Reg_vali = true;


                //Insert into database
                long id = db_class.InsertRegisterDetails(Name, Username, Password, Email, ConfirmPassword);
}
```

And Database class in android looks like this:

```
//---insert a employee into the database---

public long InsertRegisterDetails(String name,String username,String password,String email, String confirm_password)

 {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues RegisterValues = new ContentValues();

   RegisterValues.put(Username, username);
   RegisterValues.put(Name, name);
   RegisterValues.put(Email, email);
   RegisterValues.put(Password, password);
   RegisterValues.put(ConfirmedPassword, confirm_password);
   return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, RegisterValues);

  }
```

This is where i created my table:

```
 private static final String Username = "username";
    private static final String Password = "password";
    private static final String Name = "name";
    private static final String Email = "email";
    private static final String ConfirmedPassword = "confirmed_password";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_Skyetek_Login.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblLogin";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATION =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( registerid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + " username text not null, "
                    + " name text not null, " +
                    " email text not null, " +
                    " confirmed_password text not null, " +
                    " password text not null);";

    public DB_Class(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATION);
            this.db = db;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get your DATABASE_TABLE name from? I'll post the answer for workaround of this. Also you have Reg_vali that you don't use anywhere in the code, maybe you forgot to add that into the function (it might go into the table, I don't know how you structured it)

Comment: Post your table creation table

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs Check it out

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little workaround for that :

```
String ROW1 = "INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
          + Username + ", " + Name + ", "
          + Email + ", " + Password + ", "
          + ConfirmedPassword + ") Values ("+username+", "+name+", "+email+", "+password+", "+confirm_password+")";
db.execSQL(ROW1);
```

I'm assuming that the ones starting with capital letter are the keys that you are using and the ones with small letters are the actual values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll test it now @MirzaS

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign `db` while creating the database `onCreate()` method.

At the time `onCreate` is invoked a valid Database exists, otherwise `db.execSQL` will not work. However, before `onCreate` is called the class variable db will be null. Of course, as `onCreate` is only invoked if the database doesn't exist, (i.e. onCreate is called when either `getWriteableDatabase` or `getReadabledatabase` are called AND the database file doesn't exist) then if the database exists (e.g. second time the App is run) then db will not be assigned a value (as onCreate isn't invoked) and be null. That is why this.db = db should not be used in onCreate.

Your Database implementation should be like this.

```
class Database {
private static final String Username = "username";
private static final String Password = "password";
private static final String Name = "name";
private static final String Email = "email";
private static final String ConfirmedPassword = "confirmed_password";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_Skyetek_Login.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblLogin";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATION =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( registerid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + " username text not null, "
                + " name text not null, " +
                " email text not null, " +
                " confirmed_password text not null, " +
                " password text not null);";

private SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase;
private MyDatabase database;

public Database(Context context) {
    database = new MyDatabase(context);
    writableDatabase = database.getWritableDatabase();
}

private static class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public long InsertRegisterDetails(String name, String username, String password, String email, String confirm_password) {
    ContentValues RegisterValues = new ContentValues();
    RegisterValues.put(Username, username);
    RegisterValues.put(Name, name);
    RegisterValues.put(Email, email);
    RegisterValues.put(Password, password);
    RegisterValues.put(ConfirmedPassword, confirm_password);
    return writableDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, RegisterValues);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
}
}
```

Implement your database like the above method. It will work.

For more info look at this link.

http://www.journaldev.com/9438/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial

Thanks for the info MikeT.

Comment: At the time onCreate is invoked a valid Database exists, otherwise `db.execSQL` will not work. However, before `onCreate` is called the class variable **db** will be null. Of course, as `onCreate` is only invoked if the database doesn't exist, (*i.e. `onCreate` is called when either getWriteableDatabase or getReadabledatabase are called AND the database file doesn't exist*) then if the database exists (e.g. second time the App is run) then **db** will not be assigned a value (as `onCreate` isn't invoked) and be null. That is why `this.db = db;` should not be used in `onCreate`.

Comment: Nice Mike. Good information, I'll add this information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @MikeT and for taking your time out to help me. I have a question. The code above you posted contains a line:                                                                     private MyDatabase database;  <---- What is the MyDatabase referencing. Is it the current class name I am working on or what? The reason why I'm asking is because my "private static class DB_Class extends  SQLiteOpenHelper" is giving an error stating "Dublicate class 'DB_Class '". I have no other errors but that.

Comment: MyDatabase is your database class. You can rename it. Copy the above code and use it.

Comment: @Bigpoppa, code wasn't mine. `private MyDatabase database; `  is an un-instantiated  `MyDatabase` object called/named`database`. Later, in the example, `database = new MyDatabase(context);` instantiaites it using the MyDatabase Class, that being a subclass of the SQLIteOpenHleper class.You'd use `DB_Class database = new DBClass(this);` to do the equivalent, you could then use `SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();`, which would then equate to your SQLiteDatabase = db (but would't be null), you could do both with `SQLiteDatabase db = new DB_Class(this).getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it is really helped you. It will help others